# Vector equation where each element is equal to a quadratic form

Tags: tensors, quadratic-forms, newton-raphson

Is there a way to solve an equation of the following form:
$$x_i = {\bf x}^T{\bf A}_i{\bf x} + b_i$$
where $x_i$ is the ith element of vector $\bf x$.

I'm guessing this could be equivalently expressed in Einstein notation as follows
$$x_i = A^{j}_{ik} x_j x^k + b_i$$
I was considering using Newton's method for each $i$ one at a time, but I'm worrying that this wouldn't converge. I also considered expressing this in matrix form using Kronecker products but couldn't quite figure it out.

Comment: If $\mathbf A$ is a matrix, then $\mathbf x^T \mathbf A \mathbf x$ is a scalar. What does $\mathbf x^T \mathbf A_i \mathbf x$ mean? If $\mathbf A_i$ is an $n \times 1$ column of $\mathbf A$, then $\mathbf x^T \mathbf A_i$ is a scalar.

Comment: @kipf Sorry for the abuse of notation. In this case ${\bf A}_i$ is a matrix. I have a group of matrices labeled by an index $i$. This why I tried to represent the equation using a tensor $A$, but I don't know enough about tensor algebra to know if this is correct.

I'll reformat the equation to make it less ambiguous.

Comment: Assuming Newton's method works you can start with $f_i(x)={A^j}_{ik}x_jx^k - x_i + b_i$ and then $\partial f_i/\partial x^r = ({A^r}_{ik}+{A_{ki}}^r)x^k - \delta^r_i$. In theory you invert this matrix and then $\Delta x = - f(x^{(0)}) \left[ \frac{\partial f_i}{\partial x^r} \right]^{-1}$.

Comment: @Ted Thank you for your suggestion. Newton's method does _not_ work, it fails to converge. However Halley's method does converge quite quickly in my application, so thank you for guiding me in the correct direction.

For the multivariate version of Halley's method, I relied on a paper by Annie Cuyt (1985).

Comment: @J.Zeitouni I have used Newton's method and it does work ($A$ is a $3\times 3 \times 3$ tensor sampled from $N(0,1)$; then I choose a $3 \times 1$ random vector $x$ to derive $b$; now given $f(x_i)$ I use Newton's method to find $x$). Glad you were able to achieve the same result using a different method.

Comment: @Ted In my case $A$ was $1000 \times 1000 \times 1000$ so that might explain why Newton was overshooting for me.